# How to identify footprint dimensions from datasheet to create my own footprint using KiCad

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad, footprint

Can someone help me in identifying the component dimensions from this datasheet [BD-datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1486469.pdf?_ga=2.78739732.109116492.1497335113-1904665695.1497335113)

Actually, this datasheet is confusing for me. so someone please help me in identifying the dimensions and fill the following properties by extracting the data from the datasheet:

1. PAD pitch:
2. PAD horizontal size:
3. PAD vertical size:
4. Drill size:

Comment: It's all there on page 1 - what is your specific problem?

Comment: Yeah, I aware that its available on page1 but am unable to figure out the following values PAD pitch:
PAD horizontal size:
PAD vertical size:
Drill size:

Comment: Have you try [snapeda](https://www.snapeda.com/) to find the footprint?

Comment: I guess pad pitch is 7.7mm and what about the rest ??

Comment: yes I tried snapeda but this symbol and footprint not available

Comment: The pad pitch is 7.5 mm +/-0.2 mm for all of them.

Comment: Thank you what about drill size?

Comment: @kaviarasan I've added a diagram and please note that at some point you should consider formally accepting the best answer to your question. Here's an example of where you can practice the art of formally accepting answers: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304781/what-tvs-diode-should-use-for-max232-and-max485-whether-uni-or-bi-directional - it's a small price to pay for getting good answers and continued support.

Comment: @Andyaka thx for a reminder. Done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to expand upon Andy's answer, your drill size should be a bit wider than the maximum dimension marked in red. To be more precise, it should be wider than the diagonal formed by the maximum dimension marked in red (1.1mm) and the maximum dimension on the right-hand diagram showing the depth of the pin (0.8mm). The maximum lead diameter is determined by $$\sqrt{1.1^{2}+0.8^{2}}=1.36mm$$

According to IPC-2222, Level A requires the minimum hole size to be the maximum lead diameter + 0.25mm, so your minimum drill size should be $$1.36mm+0.25mm=1.61mm$$

Levels B and C (tighter fabrication tolerances) add 0.20mm and 0.15mm to the maximum lead diameter, respectively (instead of 0.25mm). Level A is usually your safest bet because it pretty much guarantees that any fab house can handle it.

As for the pitch, the datasheet shows a maximum and a minimum, and you can generally assume that the nominal measurement is right between the two. With a range of 7.3mm minimum to 7.7mm maximum, it is easy to see that the nominal is 7.5mm, with a +/- 2mm tolerance.

Finally, for the pad size, I generally try to make my pads about twice the diameter of the drill size. If the minimum drill diameter is 1.61mm, then your minimum pad diameter should be 3.22mm.

Comment: I would recommend a pad pitch of 0.3 inch or 7.62 mm, a better fit to routing grids of 100 or 50 or 25 or 20 mil.

Comment: The user is looking at the metric dimensions, which suggests he is designing his board with a metric grid. Using a 0.5mm grid, or even a 2.5mm grid, is perfectly reasonable and will achieve the 7.5mm dimension very easily.

Comment: thank you @DerStrom8 you gave me clear understanding this will certainly help me in looking at other datasheets also.

Comment: @DerStrom8 I use footprint wizard so I won't be using the metric grid. I just enter the properties values.

Comment: @kaviarasan Doesn't the footprint wizard have a limited number of supported package styles? I don't recall ever seeing this package as an option in the wizard?

Comment: @DerStrom8 I pick some random package ex: ZIP and modify its properties as per the data sheet. By this way, without using the grid settings I was able to set the pitch properties and after exporting it to the editor I modified other required properties.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

- Pitch between pins in BLUE
- Drill size in RED - use Pythagoras to get the hole size i.e.: -

Diameter (bare minimum) = \$\sqrt{1.1^2+0.8^2}\$ = 1.36 mm. So make it maybe a 1.5 mm hole.

Comment: It might be worth adding that this pad configuration will only do for 2.4A.  If the OP needs to go to the full 4A, a heatsink will be required and that might need to be reflected in additional footprinty bits if it's attached to the PCB.

Comment: The value of 0.043(1.1) is not the drill size, hole size should be a little larger to fit for the rectangular pins (1.1 by 0.8). Using Pythagoras the hole should be 1.36 mm minimum, so 1.4 to 1.5 mm for the hole size. Pad pitch should be 0.3 inch to fit to common routing grids.

Comment: @Uwe fair comment. I shall amend to prevent novice confusion.

Comment: I disagree with Uwe's comment regarding the pad pitch. The OP is presumably not using an imperial grid, so a 2.5mm grid is a better option, which allows 7.5mm spacing.